# Progress indicator in complicated silverlight process

Tags: silverlight-2.0

I'm working on a silverlight app.  When the app loads it starts a complicated layout procedure that takes about 10 seconds to

1. Load the Dataset via web service
2. Create objects
3. Place objects
4. Download photos
5. Connect objects

I am unable to show the user any sort of progress indicator that all this is happening.  With the exception of step 1 all of the steps seem to be happening on the visual thread.  How to split the thread so I can give the user some indication of what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't solve you whole problem for you, but can maybe give you a hint in the right direction. I just read this [Wicked code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dd483293(en-us).aspx) article from msdn.

There is an item in there about ["Just in time rendering"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dd483293(en-us).aspx#id0080034), it is a bit similar in that it is also showing photos, but only when they are available.

Hope it helps a bit.